# How to make animation from many images(Actionscript)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript

How much images I need to make a good animated person or someone like stickman?

I have created a class Person for example and added an event listener onEnterFrame there, so every stickman have its own animation

```
private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void{

  addChild(image[i])
  i++;


  //thus every times increasing the i++, and add a new image


}
```

for example if I have a speed of 24 fps, the images are changing to fast and the animation isn't good enough, can you give me an advice on how to do that right?

ps: how to add and remove the child to delete the unnecesary previous image? in the onEnterFrame event?

Comment: Don't add each Image. Instead draw it using graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `graphics` of the container Sprite/MovieClip. Ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html

Assuming image[i] is `Bitmap`

```
graphics.clear();
var bitmapData:BitmapData = image[i].bitmapData;
graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, new Matrix());
graphics.endFill();
```